# why searchAndSelect popup is shown though query resolves to a single row

Tags: oracle-adf, jdeveloper

I have a cascading LOV, with Department and Class. After I select a Department ID(say 1000) (inputComboBoxLOV), I will populate the department Name. 
But now I have a Class LOV (inputComboBoxLOV - find below the class table and sample data). If I type in 1 and tab out, ideally it must populate ClassName as Biology. But the SearchAndSelect Region popups and shows the single row which if selected is then populating properly.

I have tried to look into the LOV query which was firing, it accepted the bind variables Department ID and Class ID which thus results to one single row.
No idea why the SearchAndSelect popup is shown

P.S : I do not have Dept to dept list mapping in 'List return values' of Class LOV 
CLASS TABLE:

> DEPT CLASS CLASS_NAME
>
> 1000 1 Biology
>
> 1000 2 Zoology
>
> 1001 1 Algebra
>
> 1001 2 Trignometry

Answer (score 0):

It looks there is no EXACT MATCH between Class ID from your VO and the value returned by the LOV. Can you check the attribute type to be the same on both sides?

Comment: There is an exact match, and that is the reason in the SearchandSelect popup it shows only one row.

Comment: Your understanding of  'exact match' differs from mine. You are getting a match only when querying, but you are seeing the popup only because your values don't match in Java. Be aware, the comparison happens in java where "1" (String) is not equal to 1 (BigDecimal), which furthermore doesn't equal to 1  (Integer).  You  are definitely not having an exact match, from java's point of view.